# How to set only positive number in sharepoint 2013 column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, column, number

The column `Title` has default setting as single line text. I would like to set validation as only positive numbers allowed, no decimal.

I've tried with `=ISNUMBER(PurchaseQty+0)` but I still can key in negative value and decimal.

Answer (score 5):

From

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

[image]

so that makes:

```
=IF( SIGN( [PurchaseQty] ) >-1 , TRUE , FALSE )
```

or the same:

```
= SIGN( [PurchaseQty] ) >-1
```

**Note:** SharePoint does type conversions for you,
so `[PurchaseQty]` can be a Text Column,
but if it does not contain a number representation you get a `#Value` error

#### update 1

[image]

Comment: Hi Danny.. The formula works but there is a problem.. We still can enter decimal values.. How to avoid that?

Comment: Would there be a function that converts a decimal to an integer so you can check ``entered value===integer value?``.. Yes.. you would have to scan that whole list of functions and read what they do. If I present you the solution, you learn nothing today.

Comment: I Used below command.. It works in excel but not working in SharePoint. Can you please verify.

=IF(INT(SIGN(PurchaseQty))>-1,TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: SIGN returns -1,0,1 .. so the INT of that is....  You have to compare the Column itself with its INT value.  ``INT(PurchaseQty)=PurchaseQty``

Comment: I used below and still got error. 

`=IF(SIGN(TRUNC(PurchaseQty))>-1,TRUE,FALSE)` 

@DannyEngelman

Comment: There is no TRUNC in SharePoint, see the list I posted

Comment: Hi @dannyengelman 
I used your formula with setting up 2 decimal. But i'm unable to key in decimal values. Why is that so?

Comment: Because this formula does not allow decimals. In your question you stated *but I still can key in negative value and decimal*

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply jslink on List "Title" Field and using JQUERY 
You can check the number is **integer** or not.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```