# How to set only negative number in sharepoint 2013 column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I tried to put some negative value in one field for

I set negative value in the minimum value field of list setting, but it's not working

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the maximum allowed value to -1 instead of set negative value in the minimum value field.
[image]

Or you can set column validation: = SIGN( [column name] ) <0

[image]

Reference:

[How to set only positive number in sharepoint 2013 column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165231/how-to-set-only-positive-number-in-sharepoint-2013-column/165268#165268)